# How to extract items out of a json response within a list and with a word in front of it?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, scrapy

I am using scrapy for crawling and scraping some pages. I have some problems with the extraction of some items from the json response I get. The response looks like this:

```
json
([
{
    "id":"8589098",
    "sid":"3716027243",
    "..."
 }
])
```

When I try to load this response as json

```
json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

it fails with

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Simplejson tells me this:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I think the problem is, that in front of the json part, the word json stands. What can I do to solve this problem? I tried to cut the response, but I had no luck with this.

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
Julian

Comment: you have to remove `json(` and the last `)` from the response, then try , it will work

Comment: Why did you tag this question with `xpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re` to extract everything inside most outer brackets, and discard anything outside, so it will work for other variations:

```
In [1]: text = 'json([{"id":"8589098", "sid":"3716027243"}])'

In [2]: json.loads(re.search('{.*}', text).group())
Out[2]: {u'id': u'8589098', u'sid': u'3716027243'}
```

Comment: Thank you also very much! It works also perfect for me. Now I have to see which one is faster ;).

Comment: The one provided by @jithin is slightly faster, but it can only handle the exact format. This one can handle any other additional strings outside the JSON part. And I don't think you will notice the difference in the speed anyway.

Comment: Thanks - I now tested both and couldn't notice any relevant differences in the crawling speed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

```
In [1]: a = 'json([{"id":"8589098", "sid":"3716027243"}])'

In [2]: t = a.strip('json(').strip(')')

In [3]: json.loads(t)
Out[3]: [{u'id': u'8589098', u'sid': u'3716027243'}]
```